# On click of a send button will trigger a function and the modal dialog is not fading out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried couple of ways in jQuery for fading out a modal dialog. Please see what I have got

A `sendMessage` button with a text area.

```
<div class="sendmessage">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button onClick="infoAlert();" type="button" id="sendMessage" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Send Message</button>
</div>
```

On click of the send button will call a JavaScript function infoAlert() and the jQuery fading out function is called with in that. The fading out is not happening at all.

My [jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/scrumvisualize/k9a487v2/1/). Could some help to figure out the problem?

```
function infoAlert(){
    $(document).ready (function(){
        $("sendmessage").click(function(){  
            $("#myModal").show();
            $("#myModal").fadeOut('slow', 0, function(){
                $("#myModal").dialog('close');
            });
        });
    });
}
```

]
 [1]:

Comment: Please see the jsfiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/scrumvisualize/k9a487v2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I saw in fiddle is you chose 2 bootstrap js files, which will cause the conflict. So, you have to choose one of them, not both.

The second thing is $("sendmessage").click(function(){}). It should be $('.sendmessage').

The third one is your code does not make any sense when you call div#myModal show then hide it. Bootstrap js should take care all the modal show and hide action.

Answer (score 0):

If you opened up your browser debugger console, you will see that there is an error saying:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: infoAlert is not defined

Basically, your `infoAlert()` function needs to be defined within your `$(document).ready` like this:

```
$(document).ready (function(){
  function infoAlert(){
    $("sendmessage").click(function(){  
      $("#myModal").show();
      $("#myModal").fadeOut('slow', 0, function(){
        $("#myModal").dialog('close');
      });
    });
  }
});
```

You can read more about the `$.ready()` function [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Since you have already specified the `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#myModal"` HTML attributes, you don't need any javascript to achieve the same effect. Take a look at this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9a487v2/12/) with all the Javascript removed.

Also, note that in your original fiddle, you don't need to use both Bootstrap 3.2.0 and Bootstrap 2.3.2.

Comment: Thanks isim, no luck yet, but still struggling with the fade out

Comment: I am unsure what isn't working for you without see your updated codes. Anyway, I have added a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9a487v2/12/) to my answer. You will see that I have removed all the Javascript, and the dialog appears when you click on 'Send Message', close with you click on 'Close' with a fading effect.